# Number not being sent over client/server boundaries correctly [Roblox]

Tags: lua, roblox

[Client Side Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lziQI.png)

[Server Side Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/272eu.png)

(View the images above for the code)

I am trying to write a program that essentially sends a players userID and the "gamePassID" which they input into a textbox themselves. This information is then sent via remote event to a server-side script to print into the output among other things. However, when prompted for the "gamePassID" the value that is printed in the server side script is not the "gamepassID". It is instead the players username. Im not really sure what im doing wrong here. All remote events and refrenced objects are where they are in the script.

I tried checking if something was perhaps off with my script hierarchy at any point. Everything is where it should be and referenced correctly. It does print off a value when prompted for the "gamePassID" value, however it is the players username and not the number that i input in the tests.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs carefully:
https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/RemoteEvent#FireServer
https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/RemoteEvent#OnServerEvent

The first parameter of `OnServerEvent` is

> The Player associated with the client that the FireServer() call originates from.

So you effectively received the player twice. Omit sending the player, only send your data.